# OAuth oauth_problem="OST_FORMAT_ERROR" Cause?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

Earlier today this error started to come up which I have not seen before since using Yahoo OAuth for several years now.

`OAuth oauth_problem="OST_FORMAT_ERROR"`

Any ideas on how to fix this? There is no documentation anywhere about it and a Google search comes up with almost nothing for `OST_FORMAT_ERROR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a regression in Yahoo's code. They fixed it a few hours later.
It was only affecting clients using OAuth 1.0 (they are discontinuation support for it)

You should upgrade your code to use OAuth 2.0

Comment: Thanks, I did notice they fixed it. Will update to OAuth 2.0 for sure!